# @Temporal Vs @Type Hibernate Date

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a date field on my entity that needs to be persisted and I know I can use 
`@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` or `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` and also I can use `@Type(type="date")`.

Just wondering what is the difference between the two if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

If you use TemportalType.Date, you can see only that date format yy/dd/mm

**TemportalType.Date**

2016-28-04

if you use TemportalType.TIMESTAMP, you can see date with time.

**TemportalType.TIMESTAMP**

2016-28-04 11:14:02

**@Type** is for annotating custom types in Hibernate.

Comment: yes that is correct but that is the real difference if there is any... other than Type from being  used for custom annotation.